# How to show the route icons on Google Maps v2 when using showInfoWindow?

Tags: android, google-maps

Whenever you click on a marker in Google Maps v3, two icons will appear in the bottom right corner. Pressing these, allows you to start the Maps app and navigate to the location. However, if you call the showInfoWindow function on the Marker object, these icons will not show. Is there any way to make them appear, or is this a bug in the current version of Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working, but only with Google Maps "Lite Mode" https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/lite

layout.xml

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

In your Activity/Fragment call this Method:

```
private void setUpMap() {
    GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
    options.liteMode(true).mapToolbarEnabled(true);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(options);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.mapFragment, mapFragment).commit();
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

Let your Activity/Fragment implement OnMapReadyCallback and add this code to add a marker to your map:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(getLatLng())
            .title("Your Title")).showInfoWindow();
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(getLatLng(), MAPS_ZOOM_FACTOR));
}
```

=> now these icons are always visible.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I tried, it can show the route icons in Android Google map.

You need to do as following:

```
GoogleMap myMap;
myMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
```

You can get all sample project code on my github [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/GoogleMap-InfoWindow-android) and try yourself:)
Just long click on map to set up a marker, click it, show the `infoWindow`, and finally, it will show the icon.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to show those icons programaticaly ?

Comment: Does anyone know how can I remove these?